# No region has availability Azure OpenAI

Tags: azure, openai-api, azure-openai

On the microsoft website it says that only the North USA zone is congested, but I tried it with:
Australia,
East US,
East US2

And none of them work.
For each test I created a new resource imagining it to be this problem.

*Error*
[image: Service is down]

some of the tests
[image]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is a Product/Service support question, not a programming question

Comment: I don't think MS has released the fine-tuning capabilities for GPT-3.5 and GPT-4 yet. Generally, once OpenAI releases a new model/feature, they take some time to release it on Azure. The documentations are confusing. Fine tuning was possible for older models.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry to disappoint you, it seems like its turned off for now, for all regions. Fine-tuning is currently unavailable to new customers. This is mentioned in features overview

You can see fine-tuning models in the documentation is set to N/A

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1331598/which-azure-regions-has-fine-tune-models-available

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1287646/azure-openai-fine-tuning-region

Doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ai-services/openai/concepts/models#model-summary-table-and-region-availability

Comment: wow... so unfortunately it doesn't do much for me.
I think I'll have to face LLamas or see if there's another one easier to train

Comment: @Dorathoto, Also look at Databricks' Dolly. Its available both for research and commercial use. I did testing on it before and it was highly performant.

Comment: FYI this is a customer support issue (service availability by region) - not something that should be answered here. Plus, links aren't really valid answers.

Comment: @DavidMakogon, yes I am aware David, I just wanted to set him into the right direction. I didnt want to be unhelpful, and just say "go file a support ticket"

Comment: Except... filing a support ticket is a valid reply. Check out [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions on Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746) - this is specifically addressed.

Comment: Ziya's response was fundamental because Azure doesn't even support it, if you have any doubts he tells you to ask Google or stackoverflow. Joke with those who want to develop.

Comment: @DavidMakogon I think it would be helpful if MS brings more clarity in their documentation stating that Fine Tuning capabilities for Chat-GPT-3.5/GPT-4 is not yet available in AOAI. Same kind of confusion was created last time when OpenAI released "function call" feature and Azure didn't have it for days. When Azure published it, the new model version was available in certain regions.

Comment: @ArnabBiswas, agree. These things need to be stated clearly in documentation so that users do not have to open a ticket each time they have to ask the same question.

Comment: I will check azuredocs repo if this is an issue already raised. You can also provide feedback by github link provided at the end of documentation. Here are current issues involving openai docs: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues?q=openai

Comment: @DavidMakogon There is no way to open a support ticket, when I try they ask me on stackoverflow or do I have to pay for it.

Comment: @Dorathoto - billing/service support tickets can be created through the Azure portal (you can also ask on an official support channel.). Even if support directs you to Stack Overflow, questions here still need to be programming-related.  But... Stack Overflow doesn't handle such product/service support questions.